# Cannot resolve symbols for dimen, mipmap, string although the corresponding xml files exist in res folder

Tags: android, android-resources

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.datafrominternet.MainActivity">
```

I am new to android development.

Above is part of my XML file.The system says cannot resolve symbol..... for all these. I do have all the dimen, string,  written in the res folder already. I am not able to access them (both anything from dimen.xml or string.xml) in my XML file.

Similarly in the **AndroidManifest.XML** I am not able to access `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. Although I do have it in my res folder.
I have tried hard and not able to remove the error.

```
<resources> 
     <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
     <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
     <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

this is how my **dimen.xml** looks like. similarly **string.xml** is well defined too but still it says cannot resolve symbols

Comment: <resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources> .     ........... this is how my dimen.xml looks like.... similarly string.xml is well defined too but still it says cannot resolve symbols

Comment: Have you created these resources files in dimen at value and mipmap at res folders?

Comment: if you have dimen file than clean your project and rebuild

Comment: @Sukhbir Put the comment into your original question. You should try to have all relevant information in the question so people don't have to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Goto **res** folder in your project structure,  go to **values** directory and check whether **dimen.xml** file is exist or not. If exists then initialize your values like below

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen> // 16dp is customizable as per your requirement
```

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for late reply.. are you able to resolve issue??? If not, post your dimens.xml code.. I will check that